# Interesting algorithm problem

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have an interesting algorithm problem here. The problem is in a way related to simulation of electronic designs.

Say for example, I have a structure containing some gates. say a 3-input AND gate.
There are 8 possible inputs i.e

```
000
001
...
111
```

Out of these 8 inputs, if I only feed in two inputs `(000)` and `(111)`, I get both the possible outputs i.e `0` and `1`.

So The minimal set of input vectors that produces both the states '0' and '1' on the output are {000, 111}.

The problem is given a design, some arrangement of gates, give an algorithm to find the minimal set of input vectors that produces both the states (i.e 0 and 1) on the final output.

Comment: out of curiosity: is this somehow related to VHDL?

Comment: For a given circuit, it might not be possible at all (i.e. x and not x) to produce both output states.

Comment: Are the gates always 3-input AND gates, or could they be any types of gates?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to solving the [boolean satisfiability problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem). It is therefore NP-complete.

To get one of the inputs you can choose an arbitrary input and see if that gives either 0 or 1. To find an input that gives the other output you need a SAT solver.

Wikipedia suggests some [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Algorithms_for_solving_SAT) that can be used:

- [DPLL algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm)
- [Chaff algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaff_algorithm)
- [GRASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28SAT_solver%29)
- [WalkSAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WalkSAT)
- etc...

If you don't want to implement it, there are tools that are ready-to use SAT solvers:

- [CVC3](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/acsys/cvc3/) (open-source LGPL)
- [Yices](http://yices.csl.sri.com/) (free for non-commercial use)

Comment: Well if we try the first input vector, then we've solved half of the problem already :-)

Comment: @Luter Blissett: +1 Good point! I had better mention that in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is solved with the Quine McCluskey algorithm. There are also some [JavaScripts](http://logik.phl.univie.ac.at/~chris/gateway/formular-uk-zentral.html) and Tools which may solve your problem.